# How to install install shield exe file without open the Temp Folders

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installshield-2012

I am create installation exe file for windows applications using **install Shield spring 2012**.
 for this i added prerequisites all are going well, while installation If i select custom feature then prerequisites should be run all are going well.But, when it meets to run the prerequisites it open the Temp folder and show all prerequisite files,it seems not good to me.

Please guide me how to install install shield without open any temp folders.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are indicating that an attempt to install your application's prerequisites causes Explorer to appear. If that is the case, it would be useful to diagnose what the InstallShield wizard is doing at that time. For setup prerequisites, the easiest way to see this is a debug log created with `setup.exe /debuglog`. For feature prerequisites, you need to specify the property `ISDEBUGLOG` to the full path for the debug log it should use (this can be the same or a different path as the other one). So for both you can specify something like `setup.exe /debuglog /v"ISDEBUGLOG=\"C:\debuglog.txt\""`.

Once you have the relevant debug log, try to figure out what setup.exe has launched that causes Explorer to appear, and then assess why it has launched that. Perhaps it is as simple as a prerequisite definition which you can change with the prerequisite editor.

Comment: Hi, thank you for you response ...how to change the prerequisite definition .

Answer (score 0):

> 1.) Open redristributables window
>
> 2.) Right click on prerequisite and select "edit prerequisite"
>
> 3.) Select "Application to Run" tab
>
> 4.) Check if you have specified the exe/msi to launch. If its blank, it'll open the file explorer at run-time.

You need to put the correct file name in this location for every prequisite you are including.